# Does the WSO2 ESB still exist?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have question about WSO2.
My costumer ask me if wso2 can save the requests in queue if the requests can't satisfaied .
Does the WSO2 ESB still exist.
else by which module is it replaced ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 ESB is now shipped as [WSO2 EI (Enterprise Integrator)](https://wso2.com/integration/) which also has a set of other profiles such as message broker, data services server, business process server etc.

[This is a good article](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/05/article-design-for-failure-integration-error-handling-part-2) about failure handling in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In the form of WSO2 EI.
If you want to enable the storing capability and treat the failed message differently may be you can try applying Store and Forward Pattern with slight modifications.

This link give you an idea about how to apply store and forward patter with WSO2 EI
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Store+and+Forward+Using+JMS+Message+Stores

Thanks
Patil